# VPN no longer working after System Update

Tags: vpn, linux-mint, openvpn, networkmanager

I recently Updated Linux Mint (13) - I didn't upgrade the distro, but it seems that I updated network-manager. 
After a restart (that was required), the VPN (openvpn) connection stopped working. 
I tried an alternative one (that I also use) - didn't work either, it's just stuck at "connecting".

I'm getting (from syslog):

```
[nm-vpn-connection.c:934] get_secrets_cb(): Failed to request VPN secrets #2: (6) No agents were available for this request.

<info> VPN service 'openvpn' disappeared
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

- Delete the file ~/.gconf/apps/nm-applet/%gconf.xml:

> rm ~/.gconf/apps/nm-applet/%gconf.xml

- Logout of Linux Mint
- Login in Linux Mint

And it works again :-)